# Create Front-end to update hard coded array within CI 1.7

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a situation that I would like to attack or should I say, it has been given to me to attack.  The owner's daughter is one of our graphic designers and she moves images in and out of our sites as needed.  For some reason, she, and a few others, quite often overwrite other files because she is in other folders, why I don't know, when she should only being adding image, location url and title text to a predefined array.  We have explained the process several times to no avail so the owner asked if we could get some type of input page where only the values needed could be entered.

I know it can be done, but not sure how or even where to start, since this is more on the programming side vs the design side, but I am interested in figuring this out, but not sure where/how to start.  I can't even figure out, what to search for in Google to get me going.

So here is what I'm thinking and hopefully one of the genius' here can point me in the right direction.  I want the array below, which is within on of the php pages, to take in variables, then have a some type of front-end app/api, link to the page where these variables are located, pass the values from the front-end, to the array, changes made, no one touches code.

[strong]Site designed using CI v1.7[/strong]

```
$custOpener['animator'] = array(
    array(
         'block_name'=>'Golf Pro Items',
         'picture'=>'../../season1/seasonOne.png',
         'location'=>'/golf/sea_1/itemsad-items/aa/',
         'class' => 'season-range-3b'
),
    array(
         'block_name'=>'Golf Pro Items Season 2',
         'picture'=>'../../season2/seasonTwo.jpg',
         'location'=>'/golf/sea_2/items89k1-items/89ki/',
         'class' => 'season-range-3a'
),
 array(
         'block_name'=>'Golf Pro Items Season 3',
         'picture'=>'../../season3/seasonThree.gif',
         'location'=>'/golf/sea_3/itemslp00-items/lp00/',
         'class' => 'season-range-3c'
),
);
```

All this does is hold the images and titles that will appear on another page.  These are obviously hard coded and not in a db and the user/owner's daughter, goes in and makes the needed changes to image location, title, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think it could be as easy as using a form...But it's hard to tell without knowing more about your system; and besides, we can't code a whole CRUD admin panel for you

Comment: You really need to have a database backing this unless you want everyone editing code all the time which seems to be your problem

Comment: I did go on and create a db and ui for the designers - thank you.